# Why are my illustrations being removed from my question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, editing, images

Twice someone has removed illustrations from my question: [Best places to be on Earth when an all out nuclear war breaks out?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/125171/best-places-to-be-on-earth-when-an-all-out-nuclear-war-breaks-out)

I thought the gifs did a good job illustrating what I vision. They reflect my question how I see it. Should I be able to keep the gifs in my question for dramatic effect if I want it? even if they are not an actual nuclear explosion?

Will I get in trouble if I put them back?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When an image is used into a question or an answer it shall support what is being said. When I saw those gifs, my first question was: "Why is the smoke cloud of a rocket launch here?", followed by a "wait, why is Deep Impact quoted here?". And I had to read again your question to understand what it was about.

Unless your target is to confuse your readers, I don't think random images have to be placed just because you can. Use them if they support what you are stating.

About the last version of the images you placed in the question, colored circles without an indication of what they mean are, again, meaningless. I am sure in the source site there was something explaining the colors. If you at least copied that it would explain better what those circles mean.

Comment: I can do that give me a minute. I would really like to use the deep impact gifs. How would I do that?

Comment: If you want to use images of a fictional asteroid impact, use them in a question about asteroid impact.

Comment: Is it ok if I use them in an answer later?

Comment: @Muze If you're going to embed GIF images, then I plead, "unless their total sizes is small enough (<2MB), please just link to them instead of embedding it" mobile data aren't cheap on some countries.

Comment: @AndrewT. Exactly! Cross platform, cross browser compatibility! Stack Exchange is mercifully ad free; let those of us who like to run Opera in their spare time do it in peace!

Comment: Yeah, those videos really don't do anything to clarify the question. Notice that in the answer with pictures, we see a map that clarifies the geographical areas you'd want to focus on and also an image that (cleverly & humourously) underscores the respondent's point about the target bit of geography. That's a good use of pictures. Random rocket launches and people standing around like dummies on a beach during a tsunami and so forth, just no.

Comment: I have background as a technical writer - images are distracting.  So they should only be used when necessary.  It's harder to read questions (and answers) with images, and so those images must have specific and valuable purpose.  And I bet any reader - every reader - of this comment... on my hands and knees... edit your graphics and reduce their size!  200-400 px on the long edge is more than enough.  Link to anything bigger.  Cheers!